# javascript - extract array from json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, performance, algorithm

Let say We have the following json object:

```
[{"a1" : "a1Val", "a2" : "a2Val", "a3" : "a3Val"}, 
 {"b1" : "b1Val", "b2" : "b2Val", "b3" : "b3Val"},

 ....

 {"z1" : "z1Val", "z2" : "z2Val", "z3" : "z3Val"}]
```

How can we retrieve from this object array of only X2 key value pairs.

meaning, the following result:

```
 [ {"a2" : "a2Val"}, {"b2" : "b2Val"}, ... ,{ "z2" : "z2Val"}]
```

within the best performance.

The key does not have to contains number.

What I need here is a function that will recieve parameter - i
and return an array of all the i-th objects in the original json object

So for example if we look at the above json object
and we invoke the method we 2 the method will return

```
 [ {"a2" : "a2Val"}, {"b2" : "b2Val"}, ... ,{ "z2" : "z2Val"}]
```

Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Your result isn't a valid array. Do you want an object (`{"a2":"a2Val","b2":"b2Val"...}`); an array of objects (`[{"a2":"a2Val"},{"b2":"b2Val"}...]`) or something else?

Comment: is this the actual format of your data? will you always have a through z?

Comment: I expect you mean you want a dictionary with only the pairs specified? The problem is that dictionaries are not ordered. Do the keys actually contain numbers?

Comment: @Paul Roub , 
I want an array of objects.. I'll update the question

Comment: @SanjayManohar, The keys does not have to contains number..

Comment: So then how do you know which ones are 'X2'?

Comment: They are the second objects.. please see my update..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `Array.map` here

```
var arr = oldArr.map(function(obj){
    var key = Object.keys(obj).sort()[1], rtn = {};    
    return rtn[key] = obj[key], rtn;
});
```

What you're doing is taking the second key and then returning a new Object with that key and value.

Comment: Had a same thought as you, but your solution is even fancier. Damn, I like how you used the `,` in your return statement!

Comment: @Qwerty ah! You're the first person who has appreciated the usage of comma operator. Thanks for that :)

Comment: @AmitJoki , Thanks, this is the most elegant way I saw for doing that. I'll use your way!

Comment: @johnSmith glad to have helped you :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var initialArr = [
                  {"a1" : "a1Val", "a2" : "a2Val", "a3" : "a3Val"}, 
                  {"b1" : "b1Val", "b2" : "b2Val", "b3" : "b3Val"},
                  {"z1" : "z1Val", "z2" : "z2Val", "z3" : "z3Val"}
                 ];

var resArr = initialArr.map(function(x){
    return x[Object.keys(x)[1]];
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pnkovg7p/)

Here in this resArr, I am mapping it to initialArr[ ], to generate an array out of it called resArr and the each element initialArr is represented as 'x' in this x is an object now inorde to get the 2nd element of the object x[1] so here, 1 represents the second element as index starts from 0,1 ,,,so we need to get the keys of that object by Object.keys(x)[1]...hence value would be x[Object.keys(x)[1]].

Comment: pls add a more detailed explanation - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: fine but directly on your answer not on the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Just a really fancy way to do exactly what you asked. Applicable to anything after little tweaking

```
var json   = '[{"a1" : "a1Val", "a2" : "a2Val", "a3" : "a3Val"},{"b1" : "b1Val", "b2" : "b2Val", "b3" : "b3Val"},{"z1" : "z1Val", "z2" : "z2Val", "z3" : "z3Val"}]',
    parsed = JSON.parse(json),
    index  = 2, // here goes your value

    result = parsed.map(function(obj){
               var key = Object.keys(obj)[0][0]+index,
                   retDict = {};
               return retDict[key] = obj[key], retDict;
             });
```

Run this in a console and see.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find that it is more efficient to do this when parsing your JSON string by using a reviver function. Something like this.

```js
var json = '[{"a1" : "a1Val", "a2" : "a2Val", "a3" : "a3Val"},{"b1" : "b1Val", "b2" : "b2Val", "b3" : "b3Val"},{"z1" : "z1Val", "z2" : "z2Val", "z3" : "z3Val"}]',
    data = JSON.parse(json, function (key, value) {
        if (key !== "" && typeof value === 'object') {
            Object.keys(value).forEach(function (name) {
                if (name.slice(-1) !== '2') {
                    delete value[name];
                }
            });
        }

        return value;
    });

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(data)));
```

Comment: I'd like thie answer as well!

Answer (score 0):

Do a forEach loop on the array. Then for each value get the key with a regular expression. ([Loop through object get value using regex key matches Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758112/loop-through-object-get-value-using-regex-key-matches-javascript)).
I won't give you the full code because it is easy to implement and it is a good learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to array, map the keys, filter results, concat it all, etc.
This should work for you:

```
var result = arr
    .map(function (obj) { 
        return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
            var result = {};
            result[key] = obj[key];

            if (key.substring(1) === "2") {
                return result;
            }
        });
    })
    .reduce(function (x, y) { return x.concat(y); }, [])
    .filter(function (obj) { return obj });
```

[See working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87h1bg67/).

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
var collection, key, obj, objArr, _i, _len, _tmp;

collection = [
  {
    "a1": "a1Val",
    "a2": "a2Val",
    "a3": "a3Val"
  }, {
    "b1": "b1Val",
    "b2": "b2Val",
    "b3": "b3Val"
  }
];

objArr = [];

for (_i = 0, _len = collection.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  obj = collection[_i];
  for (key in obj) {
    _tmp = {};
    _tmp[key] = obj[key];
    objArr.push(_tmp);
  }
}
```